# Play MIDI files

Tags: audio, quicktime, midi

As far as I can tell, this is completely impossible. On 10.8.4. I am trying to play a sample MIDI file [off of Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence_%28music%29).

Quicktime v 10.2 fails to open a MIDI file with error message

> The movie “Ii-V-I_turnaround_in_C_four-part_harmony.mid” can’t be opened because the file is not in a format that QuickTime Player understands.

VLC is also unhappy:

> No suitable decoder module
>   VLC does not support the audio or video format "MIDI". Unfortunately there is no way for you to fix this.

AFAICT I need to go find some random obscure MIDI player and download it for Mac, which seems extremely strange given that a site as large as Wikipedia uses them freely and assumes they "just work" on Mac. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to install the Quicktime 7. Yes! you have to have 2 Quicktime apps (the v10 and the 7) on your Mac. I had a full blown answer for you but some schmucks in here keep voting it down without reason.

Comment: @Buscar웃 can I see the full blown answer anyway?

Comment: OK, here it comes :)

Comment: You can download Quicktime Player 7.6.6 for Lion, Mountain Lion, or Mavericks from here: 

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3678

Answer (score 2):

[QuickTime Player 7](http://support.apple.com/downloads/#quicktime) also supports mid files.

Many DAWs like Logic support importing and exporting mid files, but one free MIDI sequencer or editor is [Aria Maestosa](http://ariamaestosa.sourceforge.net). [Synthesia](http://www.synthesiagame.com) is an application or rhythm game for practicing playing mid files.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Quicktime Version 7.6.4 (518.35), I am able to play midi files with the free [RealPlayer](http://www.real.com/) for Mac OS X, [Version 12.0.0 (1725)](http://download.cnet.com/RealPlayer-SP/3000-2139_4-24751.html), on my 21.5-inch, Late 2013, 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 iMac, running OS X 10.9.5 (13F34). This older version should also work on PowerPC Macs.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth pointing out that QuickTime Player 7 will not work on the forthcoming MacOS Catalina 10.15, because it's 32-bit. When that OS is released, there will not be a native way of playing MIDI files.

There is an app in the Mac App Store called  [MIDIPlayer X](http://www.methodred.net/midiplayerx/) which works well. It costs a tiny bit of money, so you'll need to weight up whether the functionality is worth it for you.